# Auto update badge number in ionic 4

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, payload

I'm using ionic 4 cordova plugin FCM.
My app notification working perfect but badge number not increase unless I refresh the app.
So, my question is how to increment badge count without refresh app in ios?

My Notification payload format is

```
<?php
        function send_notification ($token, $message, $title)
        {
                 $path_to_firebase_cm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
                
            
                $fields = array(
                   'registration_ids' => $token,
                    'notification' => array('title' => $title, 'body' => $message ),
                    'data' => array('message' => $message, 'title' => $title  ),
                    'sound' => 'default',
                    'badge' => 1
                
                );

                $headers = array(
            'Authorization:key=AAAAF.....,
            'Content-Type:application/json'
        );      
        $ch = curl_init();
 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_firebase_cm); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 ); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
       
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
      
        }

        
        $message=$_POST["message"];
        $title=$_POST["title"];
        include_once 'config.php';
        $sql = "SELECT mem_tokenid FROM user";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        
      //var_dump(result);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $tokens[] = $row["mem_tokenid"];
                }
        }
    var_dump($tokens);

  
        mysqli_close($conn);
        $message = $message;
        $title = $title;
        $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message, $title);
        echo $message_status;
 ?>
```

Do I did something wrong here?

Comment: You can use badge plugin and set badge dynamic while received notification

Comment: Thank you for reply, I'm using  ```cordova-plugin-badge``` .  Badge is setting fine but, I have to refresh app every time notification received to update badge number.

Comment: You need to pass badge count from payload and set badge count while received notification

Comment: What suppose payload looks like? Is my payload wrong?

Comment: send unread message count in payload and click on app or open app clear badge so every time you set updated count